# Invalidate OTP after timeout using firebase phone authentication in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, one-time-password, sms-verification

I am using firebase phone authentication in my flutter application and I want to send new OTP after timeout (say 60 seconds), instead of sending same duplicate OTP again on resend request.

The `timeout` parameter of `_firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber()` corresponds to SMS auto-retrieval timeout and not the OTP expiration time. How can I workaround with that?

Answer (score 0):

The `timeout` parameter is for OTP expiration time